# alternate interpretations of Galois action on Tate module

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over a field $K$, and let $\ell$ be a prime different from the characteristic of $K$. Consider the well-known short exact sequence of etale fundamental groups (geometric base points omitted from notation)
$$1 \to \pi_{1}(E_{K^{\mathrm{sep}}}) \to \pi_{1}(E_{K}) \to \pi_{1}(\mathrm{Spec}(K)) \to 1.$$
Since $E$ has a $K$-point, we have a section $s : \mathrm{Spec}(K) \to E_{K}$, which induces a section $s_{*} : \pi_{1}(\mathrm{Spec}(K)) \to \pi_{1}(E_{K})$.  Let $\rho: \pi_{1}(\mathrm{Spec}(K)) \to \mathrm{Aut}(\pi_{1}(E_{K^{\mathrm{sep}}}))$ denote the action of $\pi_{1}(\mathrm{Spec}(K))$ on $\pi_{1}(E_{K^{\mathrm{sep}}})$ defined by following $s_{*}$ to $\pi_{1}(E_{K})$ and then acting by conjugation on $\pi_{1}(E_{K^{\mathrm{sep}}}) \lhd \pi_{1}(E_{K})$. Viewing $T_{\ell}(E)$ as the $\ell$-adic quotient of $\pi_{1}(E_{K^{\mathrm{sep}}})$, we get an action $\rho_{\ell} : \pi_{1}(\mathrm{Spec}(K)) \to \mathrm{Aut}(T_{\ell}(E))$.

But of course, $\mathrm{Gal}(K^{\mathrm{sep}} / K) = \pi_{1}(\mathrm{Spec}(K))$, and this action $\rho_{\ell}$ should in fact be the usual Galois action on $T_{\ell}(E)$.  I can prove this by carefully unpacking the construction of the map $s_{*}$ which was induced by $s$, the definition of the etale fundamental group, etc.  But it feels like it should be a basic fact, and I'm wondering if there's any well-known result in the literature that I can easily quote this from (and hopefully which would help me gain a broader understanding of the actions that naturally arise from these short exact sequences of fundamental groups).

Thank you for any insight you can offer, and I may post a follow-up question to this.

Comment: You probably mean "we get an action $\rho_{\ell} : \pi_{1}(\mathrm{Spec}(K)) \to \mathrm{Aut}(T_{\ell}(E))$".

Comment: the action you define is clearly independent of the section, so your question has little to do with sections.

Comment: You seem to be asking for a (special case of a) galois equivariant form of Hurewicz's theorem. I imagine such a thing is known but I don't have a reference.

Comment: Niels, I made the necessary edit, and thanks for the point about not depending on the section.  The argument is now a little simpler.

Comment: I don't know of any general reference, but the direct argument isn't too tedious: For any $n$ prime to the characteristic of $K$, the multiplication-by-$n$ endomorphism gives you a finite \'etale cover of $E$, and therefore corresponds to a $\pi_1(E)$-set. The functor from $\pi_1(E)$-sets (i.e. finite \'etale covers of $E$) to $\pi_1(Spec~K)$-sets (i.e. finite \'etale covers of $Spec~K$) corresponding to $s_*$ is just 'take fiber over $0$'. When you apply this to the multiplication-by-$n$ map, you simply recover the $n$-torsion $E[n]$.